# Print results from class - python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to print the result (number_row) that is returned in my class but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to print 'number_row'? I already tried *print NumberRow.combine_bc* but that wont work either.

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list_b = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
list_c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
new_list = []
list_ab = []
final_list = []
final_result = []
number_row = []

class NumberRow:
    def __init__(self, list_a, list_b, list_c, list_ab, my_list, new_list, final_list, final_result, result):
        self.list_a = list_a
        self.list_b = list_b
        self.list_c = list_c
        self.list_ab = list_ab
        self.new_list = new_list
        self.number_row = number_row
        self.new_list = new_list
        self.final_result = final_result

def combine_ab(self):
    for element in range(len(list_a)):
        my_list = []
        number1 = list_a[element]
        my_list += [number1]
        number2 = list_b[element]
        my_list += [number2]
        new_list.append(my_list)

        for x in new_list:
            for y in x:
                list_ab.append(y)

        return list_ab


def combine_bc(self):
    for element in range(len(list_c)):
        final_list = []
        number3 = list_ab[element]
        final_list += [number3]
        number4 = list_c[element]
        final_list += [number4]
        final_result.append(final_list)

        for x in final_result:
            for y in x:
                number_row.append(y)

        return number_row
```

---

Comment: for using class level variable inside methods in the call use `self` keyword like self.list_c

Comment: Note that your methods should be indented to the same level as your `__init__` constructor. Otherwise they'll get declared as stand-along functions not methods of the class `NumberRow`